# Material UI Swipable Drawer override the html style overflow to hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material UI SwipableDrawer component and it has an unwanted effect that makes the scrollbar disappear when the drawer is visible. That completely override the style i put on the Html tag "overflow-y: scroll" and it doesn't set it back.
How do i override this unwanted effect? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that i was putting overflow-y: scroll and the drawer was overriding overscoll

Setting the HTML style to overflow: scroll solved the issue

However, this will still hide the scrollbar when the drawer is open, which is still kind of undesired